# Why is the maximum number of open files that are started with the system is 1024 under CentOS 6.10?

Tags: linux, centos-6

I have modified `/etc/security/limit.conf`:

```
*  hard  nofile  1000000
*  soft  nofile  1000000
```

As well as this file `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

```
*          soft    nproc     unlimited
root       soft    nproc     unlimited
```

And rebooted the system. Here is the output of `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30967
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30967
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But my program is put into `rc.local` to boot, the maximum file limit is still 1024:

Here is the output of `cat /proc/1695/limits`:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            10485760             unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             30967                30967                processes 
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       30967                30967                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

What is the reason for this? I don’t have such restrictions when I start the program on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve it through the system level.
I solved it through my golang program.

```
    var rLimit syscall.Rlimit
    err := syscall.Getrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("1Error Getting Rlimit ", err)
    }
    log.Infof("Current Rlimit:%+v", rLimit)
    rLimit.Max = 1000000
    rLimit.Cur = 1000000
    err = syscall.Setrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error Setting Rlimit ", err)
    }
    err = syscall.Getrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rLimit)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("2Error Getting Rlimit ", err)
    }
    log.Info("Rlimit Final", rLimit)
```